# Accordionza: Trigger event when slide animation is completed

Tags: jquery, animation, slide

I'm using the Accordionza JQuery accordion plugin on a website. I want to trigger an event when the animation of a slide has completed. There is no e.g. `slide_complete` function or `callback` in Accordionza. I mean something like this:

```
$('#slide1').bind('slide_complete', function(event, slider){...});
```

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
onSlideOpen: function() {
    var href = $(this).find("a").data('url');
    if(href) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            //do something here
        }, 500);
    }
}
```

Remember: 500 stands for the delay (the duration of the animation). So if u change the default "slideSpeed", u also have to change the Timeout value. 
The example above is the only way i could do what u want :). Hope it helps you